# Null argument exception for HttpResponseMessage return type from API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest

I'm am trying to force my API controller to return XML. Here is the code I am using to return the value :

```
return Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, doc, GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

where doc is an XDocument.

I receive this exception : "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: formatter"
Any ideas why?

Just for fun, here is the entire response as displayed in Postman
[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In case the line you give as an example is line 46 in your XmlController.cs, I would double check under debugging if  the formatter you are passing as argument is null or not.

Comment: Did you by chance clear you XML formatters at Startup?

Comment: @Nkosi, what do you mean by "clear XML formatters at startup."

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that "GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter" gets a new instance of the formatter. I found that syntax in multiple Google and Stack Overflow searches; but @StasIvanov's question got me wondering, so I instantiated a new System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter and passed it in. That fixed the issue.